# How to check if window is "Always on top"?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

In my useful hotkeys program, i have a global hotkey which sets your current foreground window to be Topmost/Not topmost by calling

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

at the moment i have to have two separate hotkeys, Win+Z to set window to TOPMOST anjd Win+X to set window to NOTOPMOST.

I can't find a function in MSDN which lets you check the windows z order.. i was hoping for something like GetWindowOrder, but there isn't. I also tried checking the windows ex flags like so:

```
dwExStyles & WS_EX_TOPMOST
```

but it seems that flag isn't never changed, it just tells the window to set itself topmost when its first created.

Is there a function to check this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
DWORD dwExStyle = ::GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);

if ((dwExStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) != 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Here's the MSDN link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633584(VS.85).aspx

And here's the MSDN link to the extended styles - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543(v=VS.85).aspx - topmost is currently listed as "TBD" :)

Comment: its strange, i already tried DWORD dwExStyles = (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE); then if (dwExStyles & WS_EX_TOPMOST)
     {
      SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);

Comment: Have you actually checked what comes back from GetWindowLogPtr? Are you falling foul of the fact that it is hard for a non-foreground app to change z-order in other apps?

Comment: As a future reference - pinvoke.net has [a sample](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowlong) that shows how to do it in C#.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`GetWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Retrieves a handle to a window that
>   has the specified relationship
>   (Z-Order or owner) to the specified
>   window.

Comment: i have a handle to a window, i want to know if that handle is set to always be ontop of other windows

Comment: Stuart has told you how to retrieve the top most style, my answer tells you how to walk the z-order.