# How to check whether a window is topmost?

Tags: winapi, window, topmost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if window is “Always on top”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364063/how-to-check-if-window-is-always-on-top)

**How can I verify whether a window is topmost or not, when given a window handle within the win32 API?**

By "topmost" I don't simply mean the one which is currently on top, e.g. the z-order, but whether it actually *stays* on top. I gather from the documentation *several* windows can actually be topmost.

From the [`DeferWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation on `HWND_NOTOPMOST`:

> Places the window above all non-topmost windows (that is, behind all
>   topmost windows). This flag has no effect if the window is already a
>   non-topmost window.

I know how to make a window topmost, but I can't seem to find out how to check whether it *is* topmost. I can't simply keep track of the state myself since the window is already topmost before I run my application.

Comment: Have you had a look at this [oldish Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126386)?

Comment: @DarthContinent Great, `WS_EX_TOPMOST` seems to be what I'm looking for. Now just to find out where to retrieve that from. :)