# why TopMost property is not working if I start application from background process?

Tags: c++, winforms

I created window service application. From that service i am creating a process as user using `CreateProcessAsUser()` API. This Process executes an winform application `(.exe)`. This winform application having a form whose TopMost property is set to true. Here my expectation is that Form which has TopMost property set as true should always on top in `Z- order`. when I reboot the system , the form is not shown on Top. After some time it is showing on the Top? Why this issue is occurring?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't set window "always on top" beacuse of safety Windows issues.

Try to read 
[How to check if window is "Always on top"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364063/how-to-check-if-window-is-always-on-top)
and
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx)

And also try to set TopMost flag after while