# C# / .NET: Get all windows with a stay on top flag

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to write an application that lets the user set arbitrary windows to stay on top. Using **SetWindowPos** makes it pretty easy.

What is not so easy is to find out if some windows have a "stay on top flag" set so that I can let the user reset if he does not want the window to be on top any longer.

Do you have any idea to to so? e.g. **GetForegroundWindow** only returns the active window, what I'm looking for is something like **GetForegroundWindows**.

Comment: Are you interested in your application windows? Or all the windows on desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if window is "Always on top"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364063/how-to-check-if-window-is-always-on-top)

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a duplicate given that the languages are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GetWindowLong.

Assuming you have the window handle, you could do the following :

```
public static bool IsWindowTopMost(IntPtr Handle)
{
  return (GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOPMOST) != 0;
}
```

Comment: GetWindowLong is the answer I was looking for. Here is a little documentation for the usage with C# and VB http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowlong