# How do I get the "topmost" status of every window in c#

Tags: c#, user32

Actually I wrote my self a programm that sets the `topmost` status of a specific window to **true** or **false**.

I realised this by importing the **user32.dll**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

private static extern bool SetWindowPos(...);
```

Now I was wondering if its possible to get the state of the window and see if the `topmost` is set and add this to the items I have in a `Listview`.

Of course I can do this in runtime, depending on the actions I performed, but my programm will not be opend all the time and I dont want to save data somewere.

What I want is to see in the `listview` if there was set `topmost` before and than set it **true/false** on buttonclick. Depending on its state...

So is there something like `GetWindowPos` to get the `topmost` state of a specific window ?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364063/how-to-check-if-window-is-always-on-top), just need to translate to the required `DllImport` calls etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Im trying to translate this to c# whats actually a bit difficult for me because im relativ new to c# ^^

Comment: Nvm, i made it. Thank you :)

Comment: Great!  Feel free to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

According to James Thorpe's comment I solved it like this.

First I added the needed `dll` and `const`

```
//Import DLL
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

//Add the needed const
const int GWL_EXSTYLE      = (-20);
const UInt32 WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x0008;
```

At this point i recognized that I allways have to add the DLL again when I want to use several functions of it. For example

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

I thought I can write it like

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

**NOTE:** You can not do it like this :D

After this I went to my function that refreshes my `ListView` and edited it like

```
//Getting the processes, running through a foreach
//...
//Inside the foreach
int dwExStyle    = GetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);

string isTopMost = "No";

if ((dwExStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) != 0)
{
    isTopMost = "Yes";
}

ListViewItem wlv = new ListViewItem(isTopMost, 1);
wlv.SubItems.Add(p.Id.ToString());
wlv.SubItems.Add(p.ProcessName);
wlv.SubItems.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
windowListView.Items.Add(wlv);

//Some sortingthings for the listview
//end of foreach processes
```

In this way I can display if the Window has a `topmost` status.